# Finding Gradient and Hessian of Dual Problem

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, lagrange-multiplier

I am reading through the [paper](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=1213325)

In appendix A.3 Numerical entropy minimization, there is a derivation for dual problem. I am trying to understand how to find the gradient and hessian matrix for equation 92.

My education is not in mathematics and I have picked up math on the way. So, I am finding it hard to follow on how to derive the gradient and hessian matrices for optimization.

Edit:
The following is from the paper:

[image]

Comment: It might be helpful to write the primal and dual problems in your question so people don't have to search through the paper.

Comment: I think that there is something wrong with the accented letters, in the equations (89), (90) ...in (88) it should be $x$ not $x'$, isn't it?

Comment: x being a column vector you have to have x' for matrix multiplication.

Comment: I think it's awesome when a question earns its own bounty in upvotes ;-) There should be a badge for that.

Answer (score 3):

Ah, OK, I was finally able to look at the paper.  Note that
$$\mathcal{G}(\lambda,\nu) = \inf_x \mathcal{L}(x,\lambda,\nu)$$
For fixed values of $\lambda,\nu$, (90) gives us a formula for $x(\lambda,\nu)$ which attains that minimization. I'm going to adopt the author's slight abuse of notation and allow logarithms and exponentiation to be applied elementwise to vectors.

The paper talks about using the [envelope theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Envelope_theorem). In a convex case such as this, [Danskin's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Danskin%27s_theorem) is a simpler and more powerful result. For our purposes, Danskin's theorem says this: whenever $\bar{x} = x(\lambda,\nu)$ is a *unique* minimizer of $\inf_x\mathcal{L}(x,\lambda,\nu)$, then
$$\nabla \mathcal{G}(\lambda,\nu) = \nabla_{\lambda,\nu}\, \mathcal{L}(\bar{x},\lambda,\nu)$$
In English: to compute the partial derivatives of $\mathcal{G}$ with respect to $\lambda$ and $\nu$, we are allowed take the partial derivatives of $\mathcal{L}$ *instead*, and then substitute in $\bar{x}=x(\lambda,\nu)$ after that. We get to "pretend" $x$ is *constant*, even though its value does depend on $\lambda$ and $\nu$.

Using Danskin's theorem is *much* easier than trying to eliminate $x$ by substitution first. After all, the partial derivatives of $\mathcal{L}$ are obvious:
$$\nabla_\lambda \mathcal{L}(x,\lambda,\nu) = Fx-f, \quad
\nabla_\nu \mathcal{L}(x,\lambda,\nu) = Hx-h$$
Thus Danskin's theorem gives us an exceedingly simple result:
$$\nabla_\lambda \mathcal{G}(\lambda,\nu) = F x(\lambda,\nu)-f, \quad
\nabla_\nu \mathcal{G}(\lambda,\nu) = H x(\lambda, \nu)-h$$
where $x(\lambda,\nu)$ is given by (90) above. So the gradient is
$$\nabla \mathcal{G}(\lambda,\nu) = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\nabla_\lambda \mathcal{G} \\ 
\nabla_\nu \mathcal{G}
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} F \\ H \end{bmatrix}
e^{\log(p)-\vec{1}-F^T\lambda-H^T\nu} - \begin{bmatrix} f \\ h \end{bmatrix}$$
The Hessian follows with a little vector calculus:
$$\nabla^2 \mathcal{G}(\lambda,\nu) = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\nabla_{\lambda,\lambda} \mathcal{G} & \nabla_{\lambda,\nu} \mathcal{G} \\ 
\nabla_{\nu,\lambda} \mathcal{G} & \nabla_{\nu,\nu} \mathcal{G} 
\end{bmatrix} = -\begin{bmatrix} F \\ H \end{bmatrix} \mathop{\textrm{diag}}\left(
e^{\log(p)-\vec{1}-F^T\lambda-H^T\nu}\right)
 \begin{bmatrix} F^T & H^T \end{bmatrix} $$

Comment: @littleO, we should have known this already... I had to do some Googling ;-)

Comment: In equation ∇G(λ,ν)=∇λ,νF(x¯,λ,ν) what is F? I tried reading the wikipedia link but couldn't translate to English and further flow into your derivation.

Comment: Sorry, typo. It should be $\mathcal{L}$.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. I was looking to understand derivation of Hessian also. Should I start a new thread for that or would you mind expanding on "The Hessian follows with a little vector calculus:".

Comment: Let me gently suggest that if that is a struggle then decoding papers like this is a bit premature. Or at least, you should be reading them with other references in hand! I would definitely suggest, for instance, [The Matrix Cookbook](http://www2.imm.dtu.dk/pubdb/views/edoc_download.php/3274/pdf/imm3274.pdf). You don't need to digest the whole thing. This may sound like a cop-out on my part---it is; I don't think I can offer a sufficient tutorial in a reasonable amount of time, and I don't think this is the forum for it anyway.

Comment: I agree with what you say, but that is how I have learned math. I won't give up on this paper especially now that you have pointed out that it might be above my league :) , I will read your link and I will try to see whether I can solve it myself.

Comment: Understood! I honor your determination. I do hope the reference I've supplied will be helpful.

Comment: I need to derive the Hessian form, so please give me a few days before I accept your answer. I looked at your link and it seems that is what I need to further my understanding.

Comment: I'm not concerned. But note that I forgot a negative sign in the very last expression; I have added it now. The dual function is supposed to be concave, so it's Hessian is negative semidefinite.